# Getting an empty array on subscribing an observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I am getting an empty array in component upon subscribing an object from service.
I have used Subject behavior and trying to pass the data from subject to component but returning an empty array on component.

**Service:-**

```
allPassedData: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  
searchDepartments() {
    const fetchData3 = this.db.todos.orderBy('department').keys((departments) => {
      alert("Departments are: " + departments.join(','));
      console.log(departments);   //<============== ["data","accounts"]
      console.log(typeof departments);      //<========== object
      this.allPassedData.next(departments);
    });
  }

  getDep(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.allPassedData.asObservable();
  }
```

**Component**

```
  showTable() {
    this.todoService.getDep().subscribe((departments)=>{
      this.showDepartments = departments;
      console.log(this.showDepartments);   <=============== [] empty
    })
```

Comment: you should subscribe to `searchDepartments` as well, otherwise it doesn't do anything. Also you are using a `BehaviorSubject` with the initial value of an empty array, so that's what you see in the log

Comment: @PoulKruijt What should I pass instead of empty array in initial ? As I know `BehaviorSubject` takes the initial value first but here what should I do ?

Comment: A `ReplaySubject(1)` is the best fit for this. However it's a bit confusing why there is a `searchDepartments` a `getDep` and the `allPassedData`. Feels like this can all be merged into one

Comment: @PoulKruijt ok I will check with `ReplaySubject(1)` although for now I have solved this with Promise. I have added my answer below

Comment: It's a bit anti pattern mixing promises and observables, and also it shouldn't matter if you use one or the other. That same could should work with a `subscribe`

Comment: @PoulKruijt I tried with subscribe , still I was unable to pass data . Can you post and example using Subject , Observable and subscribe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using Promise

```
searchDepartments(){
    return this.db.todos.orderBy('department').keys((departments) => {
      alert("Departments are: " + departments.join(','));
      console.log(departments);   
      console.log(typeof departments);    
      if (departments && departments.length != 0) {
        return departments;
      } else {
        return undefined;
      }
    }); 
  }
```

And in component as suggested by [DeborahK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1647604/deborahk).

```
async showTable() {
    this.connection = await this.todoService.searchDepartments();
    console.log(this.connection);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this instead:

**Service**

```
departments$ = this.db.todos.orderBy('department').keys((departments) => {
      alert("Departments are: " + departments.join(','));
      console.log(departments);   
      console.log(typeof departments);      
    });
  }
```

**Component**

```
  showTable() {
    this.todoService.departments$.subscribe((departments)=>{
      this.showDepartments = departments;
      console.log(this.showDepartments);   
    })
```

No need for a second Observable (BehaviorSubject) because the API call already returns an Observable you can use.

Better yet, change it like this:

**Component**

```
departments$ = this.todoService.departments$;
```

**Template**

```
*ngFor = "let dept of departments$ | async"
```

Using the declarative approach ensures the UI syncs automatically with anything emitted into the stream.

See the first talk here for more information on the declarative/reactive approach: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSsch65n8Yw

Comment: What if I want to keep `departments$` inside a function as I am getting `Property 'db' is used before its initialization.`